# Using so/the/therefore at the end of sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions, conjunctions

How to use "**so**/**then**/**therefore** at the end of a sentence please?
For example, "*If you go to the gym, so/then/therefore I also go there*".

How to use e.g., **so** at the end of that sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Use *then* if it is conditional, and *so/therefore* otherwise.

If you go to the gym, **then** I (shall) also go there.

You are going to the gym, **so** I am also going.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it was accurately spotting my question. :) I asked how to use **so/then/Therefore** at **the end of** sentences please?

Comment: You wouldn't use them at the end of a sentence in that way.

Comment: So in what way can I use them please?

Comment: Like I just showed in the examples

Comment: Sorry. I meant to use one of them in the end.

Comment: @franky you would not usually end a sentence with either "so"or "therefore" since these are used to precede a *reason* for doing something.  Putting them at the end, therefore, doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't mean to use exactly those words at the end. It's possible to change them. what I want is to use a word/phrase at the end of a sentence to have the meaning of *so/then/therefore* at the beginning of that sentence.